# How to print the logs of snmpd(agent)

Tags: snmp

How to print the snmpd logs? We can use -D all to print the snmp logs,but it is client's log. I want to know how does the agent work process, so I want to know how to print the dubug information in agent part.

Answer (score 0):

Seems a question better for SuperUser, not Stack Overflow. However, the -D option also works to control snmpd (agent) debug level if specified when you start snmpd. By default, the logging uses syslog, so the output goes wherever your system files are stored (e.g. /var/log). -L can change where the output goes, and sometimes it's useful to use -f to prevent forking (the agent will not run as a background process); if I recall correctly, logging will then go to the console by default instead of syslog.